# Thunder Client math operations

Tags: testing, automated-tests, thunderclient

Thunder Client doesn't seem to support math operations in its tests.

Is there any way I could make it calculate a multiplication like this? [image]

Comment: Hi I am Creator of Thunder Client, currently this is not possible, we are planning to release this feature in the next update

Answer (score 2):

You can perform math operations using filters

you can use `{{quantityCols | multiply("pageSize")}}`

documentation here

https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/blob/master/docs/filters.md#multiply

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: Hi Bersan, please create an issue on our github page will look into it